# how can I divide the number of columns into 2 rows evenly in ionic?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I placed many cols in 1 row.
When the screen size is big, ion-cols are placed in a row in a clean manner, but in mobile view of chrome, when the screen size is small, most of ion-cols are placed in a row and a few remaining are in the second row.
My code looks like this.

```
<ion-row>
<ion-col size="3" size-sm="2">
    <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon name="cloud-download"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon name="save"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon [name]="icon_show_hide === 'Hide' ? 'eye-off' : 'eye'">
  </ion-icon>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon name="triangle"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-undo-circle"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-redo-circle"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

how can I make the number of the cols in each row same like 5 cols in the first row and another 5 in the second row?
I need this in all mobile devices.
can anyone give me the solution to this problem?

Comment: This is the entire code? If not please create the demo through Stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

a row can have maximum 12 unit. you can divided 12 between 5 col. and for this pattern you fill first row and another cols is in second row

```
    <ion-row>
    <!-- fill first row-->
    <ion-col size="5"></ion-col>
    <ion-col size="5"></ion-col>
    <ion-col size="2"></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

in this case i fill a row with 3 col. and also you can fill row with **offset**

```
    <ion-row>
    <!-- fill first row-->
    <ion-col size="5" offset="2"></ion-col>
    <ion-col size="5"></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

in this case i fill offset 2 unit from the left.

and for customize for screen size you can use permistion after **size** and **offset**.

```
  <ion-row>
        <!-- fill first row-->
        <ion-col size-md="5" offset-md="2"></ion-col>
        <ion-col size="5"></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

i customize my col when screen size is md or lover . but you can learn about all about this in ionic offcial